# Как вывести элемент по заданному индексу?

Tags: java, массивы

У меня есть отсортированный массив чисел с 10-ю элементами, пользователь задает номер индекса и нужно вывести число, которое находится под этим индексом.

```
public class ArrTest {
public static class Array{
    private int array[] = new int[10];


    public void UnsortedArr(){
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 20);
        }
        for (int i : array)
            System.out.print(i + " ");
    }

    public void SortedArr(){
        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.print("\n");
        for (int i : array)
            System.out.print(i + " ");
    }

    public void ReturnValue(int retValue) {

    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Array arr = new Array();
    arr.UnsortedArr();
    arr.SortedArr();

    System.out.println("\n Enter index: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int k = sc.nextInt();
    arr.ReturnValue(k);

}
```

Comment: И что не так с вашим кодом?

Comment: Как правило, в программировании нумерация всего (символов в строке, элементов в массиве и т. д.) начинается с 0. В Java на уровне языка и стандартных библиотек вся нумерация всегда ведется с 0. Вы в своих массивах можете, конечно, использовать только часть массива (например, в массиве из десяти элементов использовать только 9 штук, с 1 по 9, игнорируя нулевой, как в вашем коде), но если вы будете придерживаться общепринятых правил, то вероятность всяких недоразумений и ошибок будет намного ниже.

Comment: И еще - в Java принято называть методы с маленькой буквы. Опять же, язык позволяет и с большой, но существует т. наз. Java Naming Convention, которая, если ее придерживаться, снижает вероятность ошибок и путаницы.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.print(array[retValue - 1]);
```

Comment: А если пользователь думает, что первый элемент нулевой)

Comment: У ней (него?) массив инициализируется, начиная с 1. Нулевой элемент игнорируется.

Comment: @m.vokhm, значит, у него баг. Выводятся и сортируются ведь все - вместе с 0.

Comment: Поправила. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @Qwertiy Дык! И не один:) Но сосчитать точно невозможно, поскольку девушка (всё-таки "у нее" :) задачу еще пока не может четко сформулировать.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ReturnValue(int retValue) {
    System.out.print(array[retValue]);
}
```